# perl date time quandry

Tags: perl, file, date, time

I am trying to use perl date/time and also get file date info.
I started with this routine:

```
sub getTime {
@arrayDate = localtime(time);
($strSec,$strMin,$strHr,$strDate,$strMo,$strYr,$strDOW,$strDOY,$strDST) = localtime(time);
$strYr += 1900;
$strMo += 1;
if (length($strMo)   < 2) { $strMo   = "0" . $strMo   }
if (length($strDate) < 2) { $strDate = "0" . $strDate }
if (length($strHr)   < 2) { $strHr   = "0" . $strHr   }
if (length($strMin)  < 2) { $strMin  = "0" . $strMin  }
if (length($strSec)  < 2) { $strSec  = "0" . $strSec  }
$strDateTime = "$strYr$strMo$strDate $strHr:$strMin:$strSec";
}
```

Which worked fine.
Then I needed to get file date info using `$file1date = ctime(stat($flatFile1)->mtime);`.
Here is where the confusion begins.  If I add `use File::stat` and `use Time::localtime` to get the file date to work, the first routine stops working and gives me this as output:  `1900010 0:0:Time::tm=ARRAY(0x9a7b98)`
So in order to get both to work I had to change the date routine to this:

```
sub getTime {
$strMon  = localtime->mon();
$strMday = localtime->mday();
$strYear = localtime->year();
$strHour = localtime->hour();
$strMin  = localtime->min();
$strSec  = localtime->sec();
$strYear += 1900;
$strMon  += 1;
if (length($strMon)  < 2) { $strMon  = "0" . $strMon  }
if (length($strMday) < 2) { $strMday = "0" . $strMday }
if (length($strHour) < 2) { $strHour = "0" . $strHour }
if (length($strMin)  < 2) { $strMin  = "0" . $strMin  }
if (length($strSec)  < 2) { $strSec  = "0" . $strSec  }
$strDateTime = "$strYear$strMon$strMday $strHour:$strMin:$strSec";
}
```

... which I'm sure is not efficient.  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that there's anything *wrong* with the second method.  My only suggestion would be to use `sprintf` to format `$strDateTime` instead of a block of `if` statements:

```
sub getTime {
    $strDateTime = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
                           localtime->year() + 1900,
                           localtime->mon()  + 1,
                           localtime->mday(),
                           localtime->hour(),
                           localtime->min(),
                           localtime->sec());
}
```

For reference: the field `%04d` means a decimal (`d`) field of length `4`, padded with `0`.  Using fixed-length, padded decimal fields is a quick and easy way to format numbers.
You can see the whole guide on sprintf [in the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: ok thanks ... and if I want to pick a date rather than current date/time then I would put a date in the parenthesis of localtime->year() right?

Comment: Nicer even than the `sprintf` is to use `strftime`; see the other answer

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to advise you to use [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html).

The above core module alters the behavior of [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) to return an object of type `Time::Piece` that has a `strftime` function.  The following are your two goals performed with this module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use File::stat;

print "Current time: " . localtime->strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S") . "\n";

print "Script created: " . localtime(stat($0)->ctime)->strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S") . "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Current time: 20140624 19:18:17
Script created: 20140624 15:54:36
```